# Splunk dynamic conditional formatting

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

Is it possible in splunk to apply dynamic conditional thresholds

For example
I have a service **helloworld** and it contain multiple endpoints , for this example sake `helloworld/greeting` and `helloworld/process`

the thresholds are like this

```
endpoint,90thPercentile(millisec),95thPercentile(millisec)
helloworld/greeting,20,50
helloworld/process,50,100
```

```
Output
```

```
endpoint,datetime,execution(millisec),p90(breached/notbreached),p95(breached/notbreached)
helloworld/greeting,04/23/23,8:00:000,25,breached,notbreached 
helloworld/greeting,04/23/23,8:05:000,12,notbreached,notbreached 
helloworld/process,04/23/23,8:00:000,125,breached,breached 
helloworld/process,04/23/23,8:00:000,25,notbreached,notbreached
```

```
Query
```

```
...
...
|eval "90"=case(execution>90thPercentile(OF A SPECIFIC ENDPOINT FOR A TOKEN),"breach",1=1,"notbreached"),"95"=case(execution>95thPercentile(OF A SPECIFIC ENDPOINT FOR A TOKEN),"breach",1=1,"notbreached"),
```

I can easily create hardcoded universal 90thPercentile,95thPercentile tokens, but those will be same for all endpoints, instead i want thresholds applicable per endpoint by looking at that threshold config or token variable

Hope i am making sense, i am exhaused on my research and looks like i need to hard code a panel for each endpoint and hardcode 90th/95thPercentile in eval case statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle dynamically this kind of queries is to use Splunk Lookup functionality

Lookups can help you to save your thresholds on CSV file in Splunk servers, and refer it in your SPL queries.
It's usually used to enrich your Splunk events with static datas, and use them for apply calculations

**1/ Save your treshold file in Lookup**

--> See [Lookup Documentation](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/Knowledge/Usefieldlookupstoaddinformationtoyourevents)

**2/ Use `lookup` command to enrich your indexed events**

--> See [lookup command Documentation](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.4/SearchReference/Lookup)

**3/ Use new created fields to handle all type of endpoint**

Your SPL query will look like this :

```
<your base search>
| lookup thresholds.csv endpoint
|eval p90=if(perc90(execution)>90thPercentile(millisec),"breach","notbreached"),
p95=if(perc95(execution)>95thPercentile(millisec),"breach","notbreached")
```

Hope it help !

Comment: Thanks thats what i am leaning towards